# missing the following properties from type 'ObjectConstructor': prototype, getPrototypeOf, getOwnPropertyDescriptor, getOwnPropertyNames, and 18 more

Tags: typescript, vue.js, interface, nuxt.js

I am using Vue.js and I am trying to assign my object to a field but it get the following error

```
(property) _bodyContent: ObjectConstructor
Type 'GameComponent' is missing the following properties from type 'ObjectConstructor': prototype, getPrototypeOf, getOwnPropertyDescriptor, getOwnPropertyNames, and 18 more.Vetur(2740)
```

Html in my Vue component.

```
  <v-tab v-for="(components, i) in $data._multiComponent.components" :key="i" @click="onTabClick(i)">
    {{i + 1}}
  </v-tab>
```

Script in my Vue component. Vscode shows the error is in onTabClick on the left side of the assignment.

```
<script lang="ts">

    import Vue, { PropOptions } from "vue";
    import MultiComponent from "~/ts/interfaces/game_components/multi_component";
    import GameComponent from "~/ts/interfaces/game_components/game_component";
    
    export default Vue.extend({
      props: {
        multiComponent: {
          type: Object,
          required: true,
        } as PropOptions<MultiComponent>,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          _multiComponent: this.multiComponent,
          _componentEnabled: true,
          _bodyContent: Object,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        onTabClick(index:number)
        {
          this._bodyContent = this._multiComponent.components[index];
        },
      }
    });
    </script>
```

MultiComponent interface

```
import './game_component';
import GameComponent from './game_component';

export default interface GameMultiComponent{
    title:String;
    isEnabled:Boolean;
    components:Array<GameComponent>;
}
```

GameComponent interface

```
export default interface GameComponent{
    title:String;
    isEnabled:Boolean;
}
```

Also could I use GameComponent as the type of my field instead of Object? An how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
data() {
  return {
     ......
    _bodyContent: Object, // you ascribe type Object to _bodyContent here
  };
},
```

You then equate it to  `this._multiComponent.components[index]` which you ascribe type `Array<GameComponent>`

```js
export default interface GameMultiComponent{
    components:Array<GameComponent>; // you ascribe Array<GameComponent> to components here
}
```

Change it to

```js
data() {
  return {
     ......
    _bodyContent: this._multiComponent.components[0] as GameComponent , // you ascribe type Object to _bodyContent here
  };
},
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I had this before but it did changed it to extending Object because of the error. Without extending I get the same error.

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: Noted. That was the first thing that popped out at the time. I have updated the answer, @MikeOttink.

Comment: I couldn't specify the type explicitly but what did help is by assigning it the first component withing the data function.

Comment: I am confused. Could you be more explicit, please? Has your issue been solved? If yes, how did you solve it? Did the answer help?

Comment: I added the answer

Comment: Noted. However, your answer doesn't allow for typing, btw. I will update my answer to show how you can have typing in your data property.

Comment: Couldn't do it as an array. But this worked _multiComponent: this.multiComponent as GameComponent.

Comment: Of course! it's the first index so it's an object. I am happy your issue has been resolved.